# Visual Studio files turning to gibberish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, tfs

So, We pull solutions from TFS. The solution files on TFS are fine. However, when I edit them on my computer sometimes the code will turn to gibberish (particularly, I'll edit them, save them, close them, and open them later when this happens). It's happened with both .NET files and classic ASP files. When I go "Save As" it says is a binary file. Does anybody know how to prevent this? I'm tired of losing work.

[image]

Comment: Is something writing over them?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, what could be overwriting random files in my tfs folder?

Comment: Your program maybe.  Does anyone else working on your project have this problem?

Comment: I talked to my co-workers and none have seen this before. Nobody else is working on this project except for myself at the moment.

Comment: Can you open the files in anything? are they some compressed or binary format, or are they pure and utter jibberish?

Comment: No, I tried opening them in notepad and it was the same gibberish. When I try to select the text in the VS screen, the numbers that are in neat columns seem to be one part section, and the gibberish next to that is what my code turned into and I can select them independently

Comment: Notepad being a plain text editor will try to display them as text.  Can you upload one somewhere so I can examine it?

Comment: They're webpages, all of which just pull data from the DB, and none of which should be doing anything with the file system, anywhere in the solution

Comment: Unfortunately, I already undid pending changes and reloaded off of TFS so I could re-do my work. When/if it happens again I'll tag you

Comment: Try a repair install of visual studio.

Comment: BTW, you're seeing Visual Studio's hex editor.

Comment: Do you have a TFS Proxy installed?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the encoding of the file that you or member of your team save the file with.
The encoding should be matched and better to be UTF - unicode. 
Stand on some file -> goto file-> save as -> on the save button you'll have a little black triangle on the side -> press it -> you'll see with which encoding you are saving the files.
Make sure that all the members of the team set the defaults of saving to the unicode encoding.